# PHPUnit + WebDriver facebook, how to create a webdriver object?

Tags: facebook, webdriver, phpunit

I need to create base PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase, and use WebDriver object to get the elements from the site.

The problem I have is quite strange. 
When I' trying to execute a sample code from this [tutorial](http://edvanbeinum.com/using-selenium-2-phpunit-to-automate-browser-testing), I get an error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WebDriver::session() in /Users/mariann/Documents/PHPTests/Samples/WebDriverTest.php on line 47
```

The problem appears trying to execute this line of code:

```
$this->_session = $web_driver->session();
```

from `setUp()` method:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $web_driver = new WebDriver();
    $this->_session = $web_driver->session();
}
```

I have [this version](https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver/tree/673c098cc3771db257ea3e9bab859922ade12d62) of phpwebdriver-facebook.
How can I fix this problem of non visible basic WebDriver methods, and move on?

Thanks for all your helpful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has re-written the `php-webdriver` and the tutorial is out of date.

Let's update to the latest version of https://github.com/facebook/php-webdriver first. Then, try this `setUp()`. It is the same as the sample in `README.md` in `php-webdriver`.

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    // the endpoint of the Selenium Standalone Server
    $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'; // this is the default

    // edit the capability, choose firefox as the browser
    $capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');

    // create the RemoteWebDriver
    $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
}

public function testFoo()
{
    // navigate to https://www.google.com
    $this->driver->get('https://www.google.com');

    // get the input box
    $search_input = $this->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::name('q'));

    // input 'php-webdriver'
    $search_input->sendKeys('php-webdriver');

    // do something else ... 
}

public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    // you may want to close the browser afterwards
    $this->driver->quit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it earlier, but the same way you've presented here.